# I am using ubuntu 16.04.7. Is it possible to install a version of Pymol larger than version 1.7.2 on this ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, pymol

I received a pymol session (pse) from the FTSite server.  But to unlock it, i need at least a 1.8 version pymol.The latest version in the package manager of 16.04 is 1.7.2...

Comment: The only version in *xenial* in Ubuntu repositories is 1.7.2.1-2.2, however in a few months *xenial* reaches the end of it's *standard or public* support, so why not upgrade now?  1.8.4.0 is the default for *bionic* which is the next release after *release-upgrade*  (your only alternative is 3rd party repositories, that potentially make *release-upgrade* harder, given it's so close why?)

Comment: so is it appropriate that I set 20.04?

Comment: I don't understand that question sorry; Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has one upgrade path, and that is to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (the next LTS release). A reboot and once you've confirmed there are no issues (on *bionic*, you can always *release-upgrade* again to get to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; otherwise you'll need to *upgrade via re-install* which will allow you to jump from 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS (but that isn't straight forward if you're using a server).